# Convert Excel file into list for basket analysis via Python

Tags: python, excel

I am teaching myself Python by working through various tutorials and then re applying it to my own custom datasets.  I am having issues restructuring my data to work with this Association Rules tutorial I found

Reference:
http://aimotion.blogspot.com/2013/01/machine-learning-and-data-mining.html

My Data Structure:

[image]

Goal Structure: "[[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3, 5], [2, 5]]" ... List of products purchased by Customer.  I do not need the customer name.

So, for every customer, I need to drop the products that they have a binary value of 0.  And create a list of the products that they purchased by product name, rather than the binary value 1.

Any help here? My dataset has 62k customers, so it would take forever to do by hand

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is on the first sheet:

```
import openpyxl 

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('yourfile.xlsx')
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

final_list = []
for i,row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
    if i == 0: continue # skip first row
    sub_list = []
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 1:
            sub_list.append(cell.col_idx-1)
    final_list.append(sub_list)
```

Result:

```
>>> final_list
[[1, 2, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2, 3, 5], [2]]
```